# Spark is Giving Incorrect Results with Left Outer Join

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am doing a simple left outer join in PySpark and it is not giving correct results. Please see bellow. Value 5 (in column A) is between 1 (col B) and 10 (col C) that's why B and C should be in the output table in the first row. But I'm getting nulls. I've tried this in 3 different RDBMs MS SQL, PostGres, and SQLite all giving the correct results. Possible bug in Spark??

```
Table x
+---+
|  A|
+---+
|  5|
| 15|
| 20|
| 50|
+---+

Table y
+----+----+---+
|   B|   C|  D|
+----+----+---+
|   1|  10|abc|
|  21|  30|xyz|
|null|null| mn|
|  11|  20|  o|
+----+----+---+


SELECT x.a, y.b, y.c, y.d
FROM x LEFT OUTER JOIN
     y
     ON x.a >= y.b AND x.a <= y.c

+---+----+----+----+
|  a|   b|   c|   d|
+---+----+----+----+
|  5|null|null|null|
| 15|  11|  20|   o|
| 20|  11|  20|   o|
| 50|null|null|null|
+---+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Can you create fiddle, e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: this is the correct output:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f92d68b8e194a169f494fedcef4394da

Comment: My first guess is that the data types in Spark are strings and not numbers.

Comment: good guess but no, I made sure the A,B,C columns are cast to int and it gives the exact same results.

Comment: not reproducible with integer types, but can be reproduced with string types.

Comment: thank you, yeah at the end I figured it was the strings vs int problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Spark loaded the columns as strings, not ints. Spark was doing the >= and <= comparison on strings that's why results were off.
Casting the A,B,C columns to int resolved the problem.

```
x=x.withColumn('A',x['A'].cast('int'))
y=y.withColumn('B',x['B'].cast('int'))
y=y.withColumn('C',x['C'].cast('int'))
```

Comment: also InferSchema is not working for some reason for the tiny example tables. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

syntax  LEFT JOIN
[enter link description here](https://www.zentut.com/sql-tutorial/sql-outer-join/)

```
SELECT column1, column2 ... 
FROM table_A
LEFT JOIN table_B ON join_condition
WHERE row_condition
```

Maybe it will help you

```
SELECT x.a, y.* 
FROM x LEFT JOIN y ON x.id = y.xID 
WHERE x.a >= y.b AND x.a <= y.c
```

Comment: I'm familiar with the syntax and how it works. What I'm saying that Spark is producing different results than other 3 RDBMs.

Comment: To get true LEFT JOIN result, the table y conditions should be moved from WHERE to ON.